# C++: Simple construct-on-first-use not working

Tags: static, constructor, destructor

From what I've read, "construct-on-first-use" uses a method to create a static variable the first time the method is called, and then just returns the same variable on subsequent method calls. I made this simple C++ program in eclipse:

```
#include "stdio.h";

class testClass {
public:
    testClass() {
        printf("constructed\n");
    }

    ~testClass() {
        printf("destructed\n");
    }
};

testClass test() {
    static testClass t;
    return t;
}

int main() {
    test();
    test();
    test();
    printf("tests done!\n");
}
```

and here is my result:

```
constructed
destructed
destructed
destructed
tests done!
destructed
```

It seems like main creates one instance and then destroys it 4 times. Is this supposed to happen? I thought the destructor should only be called at the end of the program.
I have a suspicion I might have messed up my computer somehow, but I may have just made a simple mistake in my code...any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please specify what do you expect from the code.
2. Since it's a static variable it will be shared between function calls, that's why you see its constructor called just once. You are returning its copy though, that's why you only see destructors after the constructor.

add a copy constructor and you will notice it:

```
testClass(const testClass& in) { *this = in; printf("copy constructor\n");
```

normally the compiler should generate the copy constructor if you didn't implement one, it shouldn't be surprising though that it will not print a custom message.

Comment: I'm wondering why the destructor is being called multiple times even though testClass t is static. Sorry, I'll add that to my question

Comment: well, my answer should have explained you that anyway ;) (objects are being created through the copy constructor)

Comment: ah, it should have been `testClass & test() {`. Sorry, I'm used to coding in Java :P Thanks!